# Auto Scroll JS Slideshow Is Not Working

Tags: javascript

I have a code snippit I found for a autoscroll js slideshow. I pasted the script in front of the "". And also made sure I closed the div. I have a folder called images with images "case1.jpg, case2.jpg, case3.jpg, and case4.jpg" inside of it.
From this, I cannot tell why the script is not working.
Here is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = new Array('case1.jpg', 'case2.jpg', 'case3.jpg', 'case4.jpg');
var count = -1;

function slideShow() {
    if (count <= 2) {
        count++;
    }
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "<img src="images/"+images[count]+"">";
    setTimeout("slideShow()", 3000);
}​    </script>
```

And the HTML is just...

```
<div id="show"> 
<script>slideShow()</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's this part

```
"<img src="images/"+images[count]+"">"
```

As you're not escaping the double quotes. It should be

```
"<img src=\"images/"+images[count]+"\">"
```

or wrap using single quotes

```
'<img src="images/'+images[count]+'">'
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed with the quotes:

```
"<img src="images/"+images[count]+"">";
```

Change to:

```
'<img src="images/' +images[count]+'">';
```

Make sure you call:

```
document.getElementById("show")
```

After the element was rendered.

Change:

```
setTimeout("slideShow()", 3000); // Uses evil eval
```

To:

```
setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);     // Doesn't use eval.
```

**Check the console for errors!!!**

And of course make sure you call the `slideShow` function:

```
slideShow();
```